# & when (@media-common = true) - Changes not picked up unless I do static-content-deploy

Tags: magento2, frontend, grunt

In the Magento 2 lib documentation it contains the following:

@media-common: true|false - sets whether to output common styles. For common styles every time you want to add some styles you should use

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    your styles
}
```

**Question**

What determines when these blocks are processed?

While working in a module's less file e.g. _module.less, It seems to be ignored if I trust either `grunt watch`, or run `grunt less` manually, unless I first run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Changing between  the production ( with or without the --skip-compilaiton flag) and developer deploy modes seems to make no difference.

This isn't ideal as setup:static-content:deploy is very slow and disrupts the workflow.

Comment: Have you got Magento 2 set to developer mode, and enabled client-side compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to run `grunt exec` before `grunt watch` will read my changes correctly. As of how my system is set up, the common styles get complied down to the `styles-m.css` file that get generated to the 
`<site-root>/pub/static/frontend/<vender-namespace>/<theme-name>/en_US/css/styles-m.css`

And this follows the magento claim for a mobile first design, any styles in the `.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {}` media query will not load in this file, reducing the weight of the total css files.

This page talks about it some more: [Magento 2 Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_css.html)

And some examples: [Magento 2 UI Library](http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/docs/responsive.html)

Comment: Thanks, that speeds things up a lot. It's still a very slow workflow though. I hope there are some improvements from Magento in this area soon.